# Create table from dataframe to remote thrift server

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following command in df1 is dataframe containing single column Name of type String.

```
df1.write.format('jdbc').option('url', 'jdbc:hive2://hostname:port').option('dbtable','sampletest').save()
```

It raises the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o146.saveAsTable.
: java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
  no viable alternative at input 'CREATE TABLE sampletest ("Name"'(line 1, pos 25)
```

I doubt the quotes around the column name is causing issue. Need help for workaround or fix. Also what should be the conf to connect sparksession to remote thrift server directly to fire queries? 
Thanks.

Comment: Spark has native support for Hive *(if you get the proper Spark build and provide the proper Hadoop cluster config files)*; and Hive does not support INSERT-VALUES queries unless you activate a complex, clumsy, and inefficient workaround on server-side. So why do you try inserting into Hive via JDBC??

Comment: BTW, which version of Spark and what kind of Hive JDBC driver are you using? Because the Apache Hive driver is very lame, and does not support the JBDC API that would enable Spark to guess the proper syntax to use -- cf. https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialect.html

Comment: I am now using Beeline which serves my purpose. Thanks all. Your comments werereally helpfule